# When trying to install python 3.6.6 in Google Colab, I get error

Tags: python

When trying to install python 3.6.6 in Google Colab, I get error as mentioned below.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.6.6 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python==3.6.6

The code I am using to install in the Colab Notebook is:

`!pip install -r '/<path>/requirement.txt'`

and the content in requirements.txt is:

`torch==1.2.0 python==3.6.6 opencv-python==4.5.2`

Tried executing the code and was hoping the install will be successful.
Instead I get the error message:

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting torch==1.2.0
Using cached torch-1.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (748.9 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.6.6 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python==3.6.6

Comment: That's a pretty old Python version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per Python Official Documentation Python Version - 3.6.6 is no longer supported. Apart from that currently Google Colab supports python version - 3.7.15.

So you can upgrade library version and then work on your project.

A few developers suggest forced installation of a particular python version( in your case 3.6.6), but once you restart your kernel google colab come into the default setting once again.

You can also install the desired library manually instead of using requirement.txt

for OpenCV

```
import cv2
```

for torch

```
pip install torch
import torch
```

NOTE: OpenCV is preinstalled in google colab so no need for OpenCV installation. Just import cv2. Goolge colab by default support python.

If you share full code with the dataset i can help you more with your problem.